# running command with sudo and go into root (sudo -i) and run the command

Tags: unix, sudo

Question would be

what exactly is the difference between running these two commands.

As a root, I have made a custom env. variable

```
export A="abcdef"
```

then in root shell

```
sudo -i
echo $A
```

returns

```
abcdef (as expected)
```

However, when I go back to normal user and run

```
sudo -i echo $A
```

it returns blank line.

So when you run command sudo echo $A, does it use environment variables and shell from the normal user?

and is there a way to get abcdef even if I run sudo echo $A ?

Thanks

---

EDIT 1

When you say you have made a variable A as root, I assume you mean you did this in root's .profile or something like that. --> (yes!)

---

EDIT 2

This makes perfect sense 
but having some trouble.

When I do

```
sudo -i 'echo $A'
```

I get
    -bash: echo $A: command not found.

However when I do

```
su -c 'echo $A'
```

it gives back

```
abcdef
```

What is wrong with the

```
sudo -i 'echo $A'
```

command?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass your environment to `sudo`, use `sudo -E`:

```
-E    The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the
      security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
      existing environment variables.  The security policy may
      return an error if the -E option is specified and the user
      does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

The environment is preserved both interactively and through whatever you run from the command line.

Comment: Sir, you do not know how much your comment has helped a poor old man!! :P +10

Answer (score 2):

When you say you have made a variable `A` as root, I assume you mean you did this in root's .profile or something like that. And I assume you mean that the normal user does not have `A` set. In that case the following applies:

When you run your command `sudo -i echo $A` this is first interpreted by the local shell and `$A` is substituted. That results in `sudo -i echo`, which is what is actually executed.

What you mean is this:

```
sudo -i 'echo $A'
```

That passes `echo $A` to the sudo shell.

```
~ rnapier$ sudo -i echo $USER
rnapier
~ rnapier$ sudo -i 'echo $USER'
root
```

---

Try this syntax:

```
sudo -i echo '$USER'
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, but having a problem still. please refer to the edit. Thanks.

Comment: the syntax sudo -i echo '$USER' returns $USER. just an fyi this is done on non-root user.

Comment: If I try, sudo -i echo "$USER" , then it returns huser which is the non-root user that I have (just like rnapier up there)

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't replicate the results on my machine, the [man page for sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), specifies the -i option will unset/remove a handful of variables.

```
man sudo
```

> -i [command]
>
> The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified in the
>   passwd(5) entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that
>   login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read
>   by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for
>   execution. Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed. sudo attempts
>   to change to that user's home directory before running the shell. It
>   also initializes the environment, leaving DISPLAY and TERM unchanged,
>   setting HOME , MAIL , SHELL , USER , LOGNAME , and PATH , as well as
>   the contents of /etc/environment on Linux and AIX systems. **All other
>   environment variables are removed.**

So I would try without the -i option.